# Include().ThenInclude inside repo function: Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I have the following classes:

```
public class Transfer
{
    //some more properties
    public virtual ICollection<TransferLineItem> TransferLineItem
}

public class TransferLineItem
{
    public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Equipment Equipment { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is, load a `Transfer`, with it's linked `TransferLineItem` collection, as well as the `Equipment` associated to that `TransferLineItem`.

I have changed my repo function as follow:

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetOneAsync<TEntity>(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> includes = null)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return await GetQueryable(filter: filter, includes: includes).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }

protected virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable<TEntity>(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        int? skip = null,
        int? take = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> includes = null)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = Context.Set<TEntity>();

        if (includes != null)
        {
            query = includes(query); //includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include)).AsNoTracking();
        }

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }

        if (skip.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
        }

        if (take.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Take(take.Value);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

I have tried calling the above function as follow, with the use of `ThenInclude()`.

```
var primaryTransfer = await _repo.GetOneAsync<Transfer>(
                filter: t => t.TransferId == transferId,
                includes: source => source
                    .Include(t => t.TransferLink)
                    .Include(t => t.TransferLineItem)
                    .ThenInclude(t => t.Select(e => e.Equipment))
                    .Include(t => t.TransferScanItem)
                    .Include(t => t.TransferAggregate)
                    .Include(t => t.CompanyTransferType));
```

Thinking this would work, but I get the error:

> Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.

How can I include the `Equipment`?

Comment: I believe it would be `.Include(t => t.TransferLineItem).ThenInclude(tli=>tli.Equipment)`

Comment: in my case, tli is still of type ICollection<TransferLineItem>

Comment: Okay wait, my Intellisense on .ThenInclude() does not work, I cannot see Equipment, or any properties in the dropdown intellisense provides, and it shows my type is ICollection<TransferLineItem>, but typing the properties out without the help of intellisense does not give me compile time errors, so it accepted it

Comment: IF you drooped the repository your life would be a lot easier, and your code a lot more maintainable and usable

Comment: @TheGeneral Would you back that up with reasons?  This repository seems to be a good fit, but I would love to hear better suggestions